# Where condition ActiveRecord Rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm switching form Rails 3.0.10 to Rails 3.1 and now I'm encountering a problem on my where conditions:

Before I was using :

```
@brand = Brand.first
@search = Product.where(:brand => @brand)
```

This was working perfectly in Rails 3.0.10, but with updating to Rails 3.1 the same code was returning :

> Unknown column 'products.brand' in 'where clause'

This code is also working in Rails 3.1

<strike>@brand = Brand.first</strike>

<strike>@search = Product.where(:brand => @brand)</strike>

```
  @brand = Brand.first
  @search = Product.where(:brand_id => @brand)
```

Somebody that can explain me why this is not working anymore in Rails 3.1?

Comment: Your second code snippet is identical to the first?

Comment: Indeed sorry, this was a mistake from my side, I use :brand_id in rails 3.1 and this is working. Just want to know what :brand is not supported anymore

Comment: can't you use `@brand.products` ?

Comment: @SteenhouwerD It's a known bug, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `:brand_id` instead:

```
@search = Product.where(:brand_id => @brand)
```

Though as @Marian mentioned in the comments above, you should probably just be doing this:

```
@search = @brand.products
```

Comment: Thanks, but I made a mistake in my startpost. I edit the post and I was using :brand_id in Rails 3.1